# Training a BERT and Running out of memory - Google Colab

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I keep running out of memory even after i bought google colab pro which has 25gb RAM usage. I have no idea why is this happening. I tried every kernel possible (Google colab, Google colab pro, Kaggle kernel, Amazon Sagemaker, Google Cloud Platform). I reduced my batch size to 8, no success whatsoever.

My goal is to train Bert in Deep Pavlov (with Russian text classification extension) to predict emotion of the tweet. It is a multiclass classification with 5 classes

Here is my whole code:

```
!pip3 install deeppavlov
import pandas as pd
train_df = pd.read_csv('train_pikabu.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('test_pikabu.csv')
val_df = pd.read_csv('validation_pikabu.csv')

from deeppavlov.dataset_readers.basic_classification_reader import BasicClassificationDatasetReader
# read data from particular columns of `.csv` file
data = BasicClassificationDatasetReader().read(
   data_path='./',
   train='train_pikabu.csv',
   valid="validation_pikabu_a.csv", 
   test="test_pikabu.csv",
   x = 'content',
   y = 'emotions'
   )

from deeppavlov.dataset_iterators.basic_classification_iterator import 
BasicClassificationDatasetIterator
# initializing an iterator
iterator = BasicClassificationDatasetIterator(data, seed=42, shuffle=True)

!python -m deeppavlov install squad_bert
from deeppavlov.models.preprocessors.bert_preprocessor import BertPreprocessor
bert_preprocessor = BertPreprocessor(vocab_file="./bert/vocab.txt",
                                 do_lower_case=False,
                                 max_seq_length=256)

from deeppavlov.core.data.simple_vocab import SimpleVocabulary
vocab = SimpleVocabulary(save_path="./binary_classes.dict")
iterator.get_instances(data_type="train")
vocab.fit(iterator.get_instances(data_type="train")[1])

from deeppavlov.models.preprocessors.one_hotter import OneHotter
one_hotter = OneHotter(depth=vocab.len, 
                   single_vector=True  # means we want to have one vector per sample
                  )

from deeppavlov.models.classifiers.proba2labels import Proba2Labels
prob2labels = Proba2Labels(max_proba=True)

from deeppavlov.models.bert.bert_classifier import BertClassifierModel
from deeppavlov.metrics.accuracy import sets_accuracy

bert_classifier = BertClassifierModel(
 n_classes=vocab.len,
 return_probas=True,
 one_hot_labels=True,
 bert_config_file="./bert/bert_config.json",
 pretrained_bert="./bert/bert_model.ckpt",
 save_path="sst_bert_model/model",
 load_path="sst_bert_model/model",
 keep_prob=0.5,
 learning_rate=1e-05,
 learning_rate_drop_patience=5,
 learning_rate_drop_div=2.0
 )


 # Method `get_instances` returns all the samples of particular data field
 x_valid, y_valid = iterator.get_instances(data_type="valid")
 # You need to save model only when validation score is higher than previous one.
 # This variable will contain the highest accuracy score
 best_score = 0.
 patience = 2
 impatience = 0

 # let's train for 3 epochs
 for ep in range(3):

     nbatches = 0
     for x, y in iterator.gen_batches(batch_size=8, 
                                 data_type="train", shuffle=True):
        x_feat = bert_preprocessor(x)
        y_onehot = one_hotter(vocab(y))
        bert_classifier.train_on_batch(x_feat, y_onehot)
        print("Batch done\n")
        nbatches += 1
    
        if nbatches % 1 == 0:
            # validating every 100 batches
            y_valid_pred = bert_classifier(bert_preprocessor(x_valid))
            score = sets_accuracy(y_valid, vocab(prob2labels(y_valid_pred)))
            print("Batches done: {}. Valid Accuracy: {}".format(nbatches, score))
        
     y_valid_pred = bert_classifier(bert_preprocessor(x_valid))
     score = sets_accuracy(y_valid, vocab(prob2labels(y_valid_pred)))
     print("Epochs done: {}. Valid Accuracy: {}".format(ep + 1, score))
     if score > best_score:
          bert_classifier.save()
          print("New best score. Saving model.")
          best_score = score    
          impatience = 0
     else:
        impatience += 1
        if impatience == patience:
             print("Out of patience. Stop training.")
             break
```

It runs up to 1 batch and then crushes.

Comment: Did you try running on smaller use smaller batch size?

Comment: @root163 thank you, yes i tried with 8 batch size, still no success